# Java: Add numbers to a String

Tags: java, string

Hi im trying to add a number (in this case "1") to a String E everytime someone presses a button in the GUI. So at first the String E is just blank (String E = "") but if someone presses the button once it becomes 1 (String E = "1"). If the button gets pressed multiple times a 1 should be added for every press. My current code is:

```
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
     String E = (Z + "1");
     String Z = E;
     System.out.println(E);
}
```

(The Strings are set to E = "" and Z = "") But everytime I press the Button it just puts out a '1'. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong....

Comment: Please post complete code .. this partial code doesnt help

Comment: Where is the code that sets `E = ""` and `Z = ""`?

Comment: if you are defining `Z` and `E` as members of your class then you shouldn't locally be redefining them in this handler.

Comment: This is not a complete question, you are missing code. Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have variables (fields?) `E` and `Z` defined outside the `handle()` method that you are initializing to `""`. Unfortunately, your `handle()` method is declaring local variables that shadow the external names. Just eliminate the declarations from `handle()` to use the external names:

```
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
     E = Z + "1";
     Z = E;
     System.out.println(E);
}
```

It looks like you actually only need one of those variables:

```
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
     E += "1";
     System.out.println(E);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only creating local instances of Z and E. Move the String declarations outside the method and declare them as private.

```
private String E="";
private String Z="";

public void handler(ActionEvent h)
{
      E=Z+"1";
      Z=E;
      System.out.println(Z);
 }
```

Although there doesn't seem to be a need to declare two variables here so instead you could do something like

```
E+="1";
System.out.println(E);
```

Answer (score -1):

You must declare variable Z before you can use it.

```
  String Z = "asd";
  String E = (Z + "1");
  System.out.println(E);
```

Works and prints out:

> asd1

Comment: The String Z is declared as " " but it is not adding a one everytime I push the button..

Comment: You should paste contents of the whole file so we can know what is going on.

Answer (score -1):

The code you posted is not compiling, you just can not use a variable that is not declared before...

```
String E = (Z + "1");
String Z = E;
```

do instead declare Z before using it

```
String Z = "";
String E = (Z + "1");
```

what you  need / want to append "1" to the previous value in the string, no need to declare a new object, you can append it directly!

```
Z += "1";
```

or

```
E += "1";
```

Comment: But that would work because I dont want to Reset Z everytime I press it! And it is already defined as " "

Comment: While this fixes the compile error it will not solve his issue with adding `1` to the String every time he clicks on the button.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to count the number of times someone presses a button and print it out? if so, You don't need a String, and you have to declare your variable out side of your handler

```
public class MyClass {
    private buttonPressCount = 0;

    //... some code to display a button and link handler to button...

    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        buttonPressCount++;
        System.out.println("Button has been pressed " + buttonPressCount + " times.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the down vote without a comment? In what way did this not help?